# Get() pattern to avoid nullPointerException

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have get link like this:

```
record.getRootElement().getChild("Data").getAttributeValue("attr");
```

And this getters can return null.
Is there some pattern to avoid this exception without checking all results?

Comment: What would be your desired behavior in case there *is* a null in the chain?

Comment: Record & RootElement are you own class or third party class ?

Comment: If getRootElement() or other link returns null then I want to to return null in the end.

Comment: It is third party library :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
String path = "/Data:attr";
String value = lookup(record, path);
...
```

where you implement the `lookup` method to parse the path, and then perform the corresponding sequence of "get" operations.  If you so choose, the `lookup` method could be designed to return `null` if some intermediate "get" in the sequence returned `null`.  (I wouldn't do that.  I would throw an exception.)

Obviously, this approach has a significant performance penalty.  However, it should be:

- more robust than a hard-coded get sequence (where you might forget a null test),
- more concise,  and
- more flexible.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you.